# Any plugins available to integrate HyperV and Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hyper-v

Does anyone have any idea, is there any HyperV Plugin available to integrate HyperV environment with Jenkins ?

Comment: Can you give more details? What do you want to do with Hyper-V and Jenkins?

Comment: Is it possible to access HyperV environment from Jenkins ? if yes, is that possible to automate template creation steps from jenkins ?                          Also I wanted to validate the template from jenkins.                                        Please let me know if these are possible ?

Comment: I don't know of plugins, but there are Powershell APIs for Hyper-V (and for SCVMM, if you're using it) that you can invoke remotely and do pretty much everything. For example, you can [create a VM](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/automate-the-hyper-v-virtual-machine-deployment-with-powershell) with them. Depending on your use case, tools like Chef or Puppet can also help with deployment.